# Fresh OS install - Restore everything from a copy

Tags: software-installation, configuration, settings, restore, copy

I recently installed Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.2 LTS but for some issues I had to format my disk. Before that I copied the entire Ubuntu folder "/" and all sub-folders on a separate drive. Now I reinstalled the same OS on the same system and **I was wondering if there was a way to restore the programs, settings and configurations I had before**.
I mostly care about all the R packages and libraries which were time consuming to find and install.

I already tried copying everything into the new "/" and then running `dpkg -i *.deb` in `var/cache/apt/archives` but when I restarted I got stuck at the grub grey screen (as if it was still loading) and boot-repair was unable to fix that so I re-installed the OS and now I'm waiting.

Also, I don't know if it may be useful to mention but I only have one partition for Ubuntu (I didn't separate /, /home and /boot. I also have no swap).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

As you experienced, it is dangerous to take over control of the linux system files yourself. Leave that to the package management systems. Do that only if you are well versed in the technical details of a linux system.

Document your customization in a text file or note taking application, and re-implement them in the new installation using the dedicated tools. That is the safest way to configure your system without breaking it, and is equally fast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So is there nothing I can do do to (even partially) restore the system? 
For example I see R packages located in `/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0` and a few other files in `/etc/R` . Is there nothing I can do with those or any other files?

Comment: Yes, there are other things you can do, but then you take matters in your own hand. It is probably safe to copy the files under your own account back, but these will work only when the corresponding system files are also restored. You, nor I, know which files these are. Just copying all system files back *might* work if you installed *exactly* the same system as before. But even them, things may break here and there.

Comment: Alright, I understand. Cheers for your time

Comment: +1 for simply keeping notes after figuring out a problem. My own notes and backups have reduced several catastrophes (usually hardware failure) to merely short afternoons of mild inconvenience. Your notes should enable you to rebuild your entire system from bare metal, and to restore your data and customizations from backup.

Comment: @user535733 Yes I managed to rebuild the system and created a note file along the way with all the commands I used. About the second part of your message, what do you use to backup and restore your data and customizations? I'm currently backing everything up with timeshift, will I be able to restore everything with that on a new installation (same system)?

Comment: Since you just rebuilt your system, now is a very good time to test how you would restore data and customizations. Backups are only as good as your ability to restore from them on a bad day when everything has gone wrong. My own systems use duplicity...because that's what I'm most comfortable using on such a bad day.

Comment: Timeshift should also be good. Preferably have it store the backup on a separate drive. If you need to reinstall,you will need to reinstall exactly the same Ubuntu version in order to be able to restore with Timeshift. Note Timeshift is *not* a solution to backup your personal data. It is aimed to take system snapshots so one can go back to a "previous state" of the system.